# @published not working with array of types, but works fine with single type

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, observableobject

I am testing very simple code, having one class that’s confirming to `@ObservableObject` protocol, and that has two `@Published` property one that’s taking array of my custom `type` objects, and other is just a normal `type` of same class. I have two views where parent holds single source of truth, it has a `List` and a `navigationLink`. NavigationLink is passing `@Published` array objects as `Binding` to subView.

**Problem-:**

When I am typing in `TextField`, the view is not updating. It’s modifying the `@Published` object property, but not updating the subview. This is only happening when I test with `Array` of objects, but now if I comment `array` of objects property and simple use another one (without array), it’s updating fine.

Can anyone explain reason behind, is it a bug? Or `Array` are doing some thing else behind the scene?

**Not Working example-:**

```
import SwiftUI


struct Person: Identifiable {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String = "Tushar"
    var age: Int = 25
    
    init(name: String,age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

 class PersonStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: [Person] = [Person(name:"foo",age:23),Person(name:"foobar",age:23)]
    //@Published var name: Person = Person(name:"foo",age:23)
}

struct ContentViewsss: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var store = PersonStore()
    
    @State var isEditing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(store.name.indices){ index in
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentViewsss1(store: $store.name[index])) {
                    Text("Edit")
                }
            }.navigationTitle(“Welcome")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentViewsss1: View {
    
    @Binding var store: Person

    var body: some View {
        TextField("My Text", text: $store.name)
        Text(store.name)
    }
}
```

**Working Example-:**

```
import SwiftUI


struct Person: Identifiable {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String = "Tushar"
    var age: Int = 25
    
    init(name: String,age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

 class PersonStore: ObservableObject {
   // @Published var name: [Person] = [Person(name:"foo",age:23),Person(name:"foobar",age:23)]
    @Published var name: Person = Person(name:"foo",age:23)
}

struct ContentViewsss: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var store = PersonStore()
    
    @State var isEditing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{ 
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentViewsss1(store: $store.name)) {
                    Text("Edit")
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Welcome")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentViewsss1: View {
    
    @Binding var store: Person

    var body: some View {
        TextField("My Text", text: $store.name)
        Text(store.name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the array, per say, that's causing the issue -- it's the `List`. You'll see that with your original code, if you change the `List` to `ForEach`, it'll work. I'm not *exactly* sure where the breakdown happens, and it's even more subtle than one might think.

My suggestion is to use an intermediary view model. The following code works:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var person : Person {
        didSet {
            binding.wrappedValue = person
        }
    }
    var binding : Binding<Person>
    
    init(withPersonBinding person: Binding<Person>) {
        self.person = person.wrappedValue
        self.binding = person
    }
}

struct ContentViewsss1: View {
    //@Binding var store: Person
    @ObservedObject var store : ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("My Text", text: $store.person.name)
        Text(store.person.name)
    }
}
```

Which gets called like this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: ContentViewsss1(store: ViewModel(withPersonBinding: $store.name[index]))) {
   Text("Edit")
}
```

Now, here's the really weird bit. If you go back to your original code and modify your detail view to this:

```
struct ContentViewsss1: View {
    
    @Binding var store: Person
    @State private var txt = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("My Text", text: $store.name)
        Text(store.name)
        TextField("Other text", text: $txt)
    }
}
```

You'll see that if you edit the first text field, your changes will not be reflected (as you were experiencing). **BUT**, as soon as you change the text in the second field, the change in @State triggers it to also check the @Binding, and the field is updated. Which, again, only happens with `List` and not `ForEach`. The mysteries of SwiftUI...

Comment: I guess I also faced it when I placed for each inside the list, then also it didn't work. It's really mysteries of SwiftUi. But, thanks for the suggestions solutions.

Comment: In my testing List { ForEach { } } exhibits this behavior, but ForEach alone does not